# can't read multipe text files through a loop in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am trying to read multiple text files at a time. where the first line is making the difference between text files while text files name are same. i am using the following code which can read only one text file but not the whole. Please help me out. 
 Here is my controller code

```
def index
  Dir.chdir("/home/sbrc/sukanta/opengrok") 
  @f = Dir.glob("**/*.txt") 

  i = 0
  @params = []
  while i<@f.length
    data = IO.readlines("/home/sbrc/sukanta/opengrok/"+@f[i])

    if  data[0] == "JBP PROD\n" 
      #@project = data[1]
      # @cl = data[4]
      @params = data[1]
    end
    i+=1
  end

end
```

My view file code is and showing undefined method `each' for "ARUBA-I8262-SLIM-03\n":String
where "ARUBA-I8262-SLIM-03\n is the 2nd line of text.

```
<% @params.each do |pro| %>
 <%= pro %>
<% end %>
```

Here i am getting data from only one text file

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance." We need some sample data. It looks like you're changing the code and where the target lines are, by commenting things out. Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
@params = data[1]
```

to

```
@params << data[1]
```

Or better refactor the code a bit, something like

```
def index
  @params = []
  Dir.glob("/home/sbrc/sukanta/opengrok/*.txt") do |file|
    data = IO.readlines(file)
    @params << [data[1], data[4]].join('@') if  data[0] == "JBP PROD\n"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more question as i am new with RoR. Ii i want get two lines data at a time like data[4] and data[1] then how to append it.

Comment: What do you like to do with these lines? Show in view separately or joined? Or something else?

Comment: joined like line4 @ line 1

Comment: Thank you dimuch but this cant load files, showing empty array and what if i want those two lines separately as i might need data[1] to another place.

Comment: text files are in different directory under opengrok

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in:

```
@params = data[1]
```

You're overwriting it with a single String value instead of it being an array. That's why there is no `each` method.

I'd write the code more like this:

```
def index

  @params = []

  Dir.chdir("/some/path/to/files") do

    Dir.glob("**/*.txt").each do |text_file|

      File.open(text_file, 'r') do |fi|

        line1 = fi.gets
        line2 = fi.gets

        @params << line2.chomp if ((line1.chomp == 'JBP PROD') && line2)

      end
    end
  end
end
```

[`Dir.chdir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) with a block will change to the specified directory, then pop the original directory when the block exits.

[`Dir.glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) returns an array, so it's idiomatic in Ruby to iterate over that array, rather than try to index into it and loop over the array. There are many reasons why, but they boil down to a reduction in errors.

[`fi.gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-gets) reads a single line from the input file. There's no reason to read an entire using `readlines`, which reads all the file into memory at once. That's called "slurping" and is not a good practice unless you absolutely are sure the file will never exceed the free memory. Instead, perform line I/O, which is nearly as fast and isn't prone to the same memory constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your detail information but showing error "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" in line " IO.open(text_file, 'r') do |fi|"  text files are in different directory under opengrok

Comment: Like I said, I couldn't test the code. I don't have the files, or sample data because you didn't supply them, and I'm not going to take the time to make substitutes. Perhaps if you'd follow "[Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" I could help more.

Comment: @sukanta, I made some minor changes to the code to work with generic text in my source directory. It's still not fully tested, but it'll recursively descend and read the files.